# Facets using multivalued fields in Elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch, search, facet, elasticsearch-aggregation

Below an exemple of the facets I have for the moment for the field "attr_matiere_du_manche"

```
{"attr_matiere_du_manche":{"doc_count_error_upper_bound":0,"sum_other_doc_count":0,"buckets":[{"key":"Bimatière","doc_count":5},{"key":"Bimatière,Bois","doc_count":1},{"key":"Plastique","doc_count":1}]}}
```

I'd like to separate "Bimatière,Bois", e.g.

```
{"attr_matiere_du_manche":{"doc_count_error_upper_bound":0,"sum_other_doc_count":0,"buckets":[{"key":"Bimatière","doc_count":6},{"key":"Bois","doc_count":1},{"key":"Plastique","doc_count":1}]}}
```

I tried to use a custom filter

```
{"split_values":{"type":"pattern_capture","preserve_original":true,"patterns":["([^,]+)"]}}
```

And a custom analyzer

```
{"split_attr":{"filter":["asciifolding","french_elision","lowercase","synonym","french_stop","split_values"],"tokenizer":"standard"}}
```

Here is the mapping of this field

```
{"attr_matiere_du_manche":{"type":"keyword","store":true,"fields":{"raw":{"type":"keyword","store":true},"split":{"type":"text","store":true,"analyzer":"split_attr"}}}}
```

I'm using Elasticsearch 7.17.9.

Do you know how can I separate the values?

Thanks